# local coordinates of window changed after applying setWindowLong and setWindowPos functions.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jna, user32, kernel32

I am trying to remove the borders and title bar from a game application made in unity3d.

for doing so I am doing the following operation

```
private HWND removeWindowBorders(HWND hWnd) {
    try {
        long lStyle = GetWindowLongW(hWnd.getPointer(), GWL_STYLE);
        long WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000L;
        long WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000L;
        long WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000L;
        lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
        SetWindowLongW(hWnd,GWL_STYLE,lStyle);

        long lExStyle = GetWindowLongW(hWnd.getPointer(), GWL_EXSTYLE);
        long WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x00000001L;
        long WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200L;
        long WS_EX_STATICEDGE = 0x00020000L;
        lExStyle &= ~(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE);
        SetWindowLongW(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,lExStyle);
    }
    catch (LastErrorException e) {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
    return hWnd;
}

unityHandle = removeWinBorders(unityHandle); // unityHandle is HWND of unity app.
SetWindowPosF(unityHandle,null,100,50,0,0,0x0020 | 0x0001 | 0x0008);
```

Now, after doing so, the unity app window's border and titlebar is successfully removed, but the coordinate of starting pixel is changed. In other words, It is something like :

- When Unity Application border and title bar are intact then (0,0,0) location is bottom left corner of the game,
- Now after border and title bar removal, the (0,0,0) position is shifted up to the number of pixels equal to the width of title bar (I think so, some 20-30 pixels). I didn't understand why it happened like that. I put some mouse controls in unity3d game, which are not working after border removal. I know I can put unityGame in fullscreen mode, I want to make it windowed only without titlebar and borders.

Any help will be appreciable. 
Thanks.